# Django: How to filter and get results that include all the keywords searched

Tags: django, search, filter

I have a list of posts that I filter with a simple search function that gets results based on a list of queries. It works fine when I use one keyword but when I search for multiple keywords the first one is considered and the others are ignored.

So for example, if I search for 'wood' I'll get all the results that contain 'wood' (included in the content description or the name of the post) but if I search for 'wood panels' I still just get the results that include 'wood', Instead, I want to get ONLY the results that contain both keywords 'wood panels'.

```
def searchimages(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    queryset= request.GET.get('q', '').split(" ")

    submitbutton= request.GET.get('submit')

    if queryset is not None:

        queryset_list1= Q()

        for query in queryset:
            queryset_list1 |= (
            Q(name__icontains=query) |
            Q(content__icontains=query) |
            Q(format__icontains=query) |
            Q(contentdetail__icontains=query)
            )

            results = Image.objects.filter(queryset_list1).distinct().order_by('-date_posted')


            context={'results': results,
            'submitbutton': submitbutton}

            return render(request, 'search/search.html', context)

        else:
            return render(request, 'search/search.html')

    else:
        return render(request, 'search/search.html')
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: I am not sure but is your code indented properly? Or is it just that you didn't format it properly in the question? Because you seem to be making the context and returning the rendered template inside the loop.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat yes, it was indented the wrong way, It was my mistake when I copied the code, I'll update it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your indentation as I said in my comment. You are returning inside your for loop. Change your code to:

```
def searchimages(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        queryset= request.GET.get('q', '').split(" ")
        submitbutton= request.GET.get('submit')
        if queryset is not None:
            queryset_list1= Q()
            for query in queryset:
                queryset_list1 |= (
                Q(name__icontains=query) |
                Q(content__icontains=query) |
                Q(format__icontains=query) |
                Q(contentdetail__icontains=query)
                )
            results = Image.objects.filter(queryset_list1).distinct().order_by('-date_posted')
            context={'results': results,
            'submitbutton': submitbutton}
            return render(request, 'search/search.html', context)
        else:
            return render(request, 'search/search.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'search/search.html')
```

Comment: You're right @Abdul Aziz Barkat I was not understanding it! Such a stupid mistake, Thank you!
Now I'm getting all the results that contain at least one keyword searched, but I'm still not understanding how should I filter it in order to get JUST the results that contain all the keywords?

Comment: @LorenzoScodeller instead of ORing you want to be ANDing with `queryset_list1`

Comment: I already tried to use the & instead of the |  in query_list1 but when I do that I get no results at all, even when searching just one keyword.

Comment: @LorenzoScodeller by ANDing i mean `queryset_list1 &= ...` (The part `...` would be same as the ORed Q objects you have currently)

Comment: Oook! I didn't know you could define a list of Q objects this way!
Now Everything is working perfectly! Thank you so Much @AbdulAzizBarkat

Answer (score 0):

why not just use querysets?

you can define QuerySet.as_manager() in your model and define a queryset for search.

Comment: I read the documentation on managers but I don't get how this could solve my problem. I could specify values for filtering in each field in my model which will help in returning specific results related to these fields but I don't see how this would help me to get ONLY the results that contain all the keywords searched.

Answer (score 0):

So as @AbdulAzizBarkat said I was doing a stupid mistake indenting the function the wrong way and using the |= instead &= in my Q object list.

Here it goes the full corrected code that might be useful to someone:

```
def searchimages(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        queryset= request.GET.get('q', '').split(" ")
        submitbutton= request.GET.get('submit')
        if queryset is not None:
            queryset_list1= Q()
            for query in queryset:
                queryset_list1 &= (
                Q(name__icontains=query) |
                Q(content__icontains=query) |
                Q(format__icontains=query) |
                Q(contentdetail__icontains=query)
                )
            results = Image.objects.filter(queryset_list1).distinct().order_by('-date_posted')
            context={'results': results,
            'submitbutton': submitbutton}
            return render(request, 'search/search.html', context)
        else:
            return render(request, 'search/search.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'search/search.html')
```